# What's this grammar in ocaml?

Tags: ocaml

I am new to ocaml,I found this type def in ocaml doc:
https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/111.28.00/doc/async_extra/#Tcp.Where_to_listen.t

```
type ('address, 'listening_on) t
type inet = (Import.Socket.Address.Inet.t, int) t
```

I have not seen this grammar in 《real world ocaml》 and other place,is that a convenient grammar to

```
type inet = {
address:Import.Socket.Address.Inet.t,
listening_on:int)} ?
```

Can you teach me which book or doc cover the grammar?I want to learn it's details,thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a parametric type with several type parameters (in terms of grammar, it's the production `typexpr ::= ( typexpr { , typexpr } ) typeconstr` [here](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/types.html)).

For example `'a list` is the type of lists whose elements have type `'a`. This means that `list` is a parametric type with one argument (the type of elements).

It's possible for such a type to have several parameters. For example, if you want to build a dictionary of key and values using a list of pairs, you can use a `('a * 'b) list` (a list whose elements are pairs - each pair has a `'a` first component and a `'b` first component). For example, `[(3, true); (2, false)] : (int * bool) list`.

If you want to give a name to that type, it has 2 arguments: `'a` and `'b`. The syntax to define that is:

```
type ('a, 'b) dict = ('a * 'b) list
```

And as for normal function arguments, you can use the names you like:

```
type ('key, 'value) dict = ('key * 'value) list
```

Then you can use this type in your code, like `[(3, true); (2, false)] : (int, bool) dict`.